# Using method of separation of variables to find special and typically solutions of $\frac{dy}{dx}=|y|^{\frac13}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I've got the special solution which is $y=0$.
In terms of separating the variables and integrating, I know it involves sgn but I'm struggling to complete it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please explain how did you find y=0, this will show your attempt and prevent voting for close your question.

Comment: Hi! So I know that if you equate the y part of the question (y^1/3), the special solution is obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm y^{\frac13}$$

$$\int y^{-\frac13} dy=\pm \int dx$$

Can you finish it?

Comment: Actually $| y|\ne\pm y$

Comment: @Raffaele $|t|=p\implies t=\pm p \implies \pm t = p$